# Pact consumer junit5 - No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer mockServer]

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, pact

I am figuring out how to implement consumer driven contract testing using pact junit5. But the test keeps failing because of no parameter resolver for the injected MockServer, even though the test class is extended with PactConsumerTestExt. My understanding is the parameter resolver for MockServer should be provided with PactConsumerTestExt extension. Would be great if anyone could help me out here!!

Java version : 11

Spring boot version : 2.6.1

Pact library used :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

My consumer pact test class with one interaction :

```
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslJsonBody;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.dsl.PactDslWithProvider;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactTestFor;
import au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.ProviderType;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.RequestResponsePact;
import au.com.dius.pact.core.model.annotations.Pact;
import com.divyaa.consumer.beans.Product;
import com.divyaa.consumer.services.ProductService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@ExtendWith(PactConsumerTestExt.class)
public class AddProductPact {

    @Pact(provider = "ProviderService", consumer = "ConsumerService")
    public RequestResponsePact createPact(PactDslWithProvider builder){
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        PactDslJsonBody body = new PactDslJsonBody()
                .stringType("id","10")
                .stringType("type", "CREDIT_CARD")
                .stringType("name", "Gem Visa");
        return builder
                .given("Product doesn't exist")
                .uponReceiving("Add product")
                    .path("/products")
                    .method("POST")
                .willRespondWith()
                    .status(200)
                    .headers(headers)
                    .body(body)
                .toPact();
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(providerName = "ProviderService", providerType = ProviderType.ASYNCH)
    public void example(MockServer mockServer){
        Product expectedProduct = new Product();
        expectedProduct.setId("10");
        expectedProduct.setType("CREDIT_CARD");
        expectedProduct.setName("Gem Visa");
        List<Product> expected = Arrays.asList(expectedProduct);

        String baseUrl = mockServer.getUrl();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .rootUri(baseUrl)
                .build();
        Product product = new ProductService(restTemplate).addProduct(expectedProduct);

        assertEquals(expected, product);
    }
}
```

The above test fails with following error :

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer mockServer] in method [public void AddProductPact.example(au.com.dius.pact.consumer.MockServer)].

    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameter(ExecutableInvoker.java:200)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:183)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.resolveParameters(ExecutableInvoker.java:144)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:96)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

I noticed I was using org.junit.Test instead of org.junit.jupiter.api.Test, but got the same error even after changing.

Tried using ParametrizedTest, but my test got ignored.

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:61332', transport: 'socket'

Test ignored.
11:10:22.545 [main] INFO au.com.dius.pact.consumer.junit5.PactConsumerTestExt - Writing pacts out to default directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of `@PactTestFor` method still needs to use version 3.

```
@Test
@PactTestFor(providerName = PACT_PROVIDER, port = "8080", pactVersion = PactSpecVersion.V3)
```